# Run a program off a Network Share

Tags: networking, cifs, shortcut-file

I am trying to make a shortcut of some sort, hopefully a .desktop file, to run a jar file from a network share. I want to be able to do this without mounting the drive is possible. I've looked a few other posts on this site, and most talk about using Nautilus or some fileshare program to open a path to the file, but I want to be able to run the file from the network drive. Any help is appreciated.

I've been working on an alternative with a drive that mounts on login. The current setup I'm trying is to get a script to run at login using environmental variables. I've tried a number of the CIFS options, but nothing seems to work without prompting for the user's password.

My fstab file has the following:

```
//share.domain.com/folder /mnt/folder cifs noauto,users 0 0
```

I have a small shell script to mount it.

```
mount /mnt/folder
```

Is there any way to get the drive to mount without the user typing in their password? **Note:** this should work for multiple users on the system. So a credentials file isn't optimal.

Comment: multiple simultaneous users? how do you propose mounting something multiple times in the same place?

Comment: @MarcB No, not simultaneous. Mulitple users need to be able to use the script to mount the drive. There were some sites that suggested using the `credentials=/home/user/.cred` with the .cred file containing credentials for one user. I need something that isn't dependant on a file.